# How can I get a 3D point from 2D screen touch using anchor coordinates?

Tags: android, arcore, aranchor

I'm making an ARCore app. I want to get a 3D point from user's screen touch using anchor coordinates not world coordinates.

I need to get a 3D point based on an anchor coordinates so that I can restore the object at the same location later using the anchor.